# How to toggle iAd visibility spritekit

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit, iad

I have this SpriteKit app where I want to have a add show up on the main menu, and when the player dies.
I already have NSNotifiactions setup. I just want to know how to toggle the visibility of the iAd.

I have tried 3 things:

1. Alpha - I was told this would work but it didn't:

   `[banner setAlpha:0]`
2. "self.canDisplayBannerAds":

   `self.canDisplayBannerAds=NO;`
3. Removing Banner from subview:

   `[banner removeFromSuperview]`

Sounds kinda weird right? If you know please write an answer!

Answer (score 1):

for example

ViewController.m

```
@import <iAd>;

@interface ViewController () <GameSceneDelegate,ADBannerViewDelegate>

_bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
_bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - _bannerView.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, _bannerView.frame.size.height);
_bannerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth; 
_bannerView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:_bannerView];
```

if you want to hide ad use this: `_bannerView.hidden = YES;`